# React Native Get Optimized Image Source from URI

Tags: javascript, react-native, image

I have a request from the server that returns a JSON with and image like this:

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "image": "https://image-url.jpg",
      "name": "Test",
    },
```

Here is the image with the size of 108x108 (technically, @1x), but there are also other sizes for images available on the server. If we use the same link but add `@2x` before `.jpg` we would get higher quality image, the same goes for @3x:

```
https://image-url@3x.jpg
```

When i use `<Image/>` component i use the link like so:

```
<Image 
   source={data.image}
   style={{width: 108, height: 108}}
/>
```

but it would show the "@1x" image which is not desired.

So, How to make it use @3x automatically without creating a split-modify function or using native embedding like described in docs?

[Image React Native Docs](https://reactnative.dev/docs/images)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the documentation it is build-time functionality, not a runtime. This means you need to implement your logic by yourself using https://reactnative.dev/docs/dimensions for example.

Comment: you mean to use dimensions to modify the link, right? 

Also, what about the runtime lib like `react-retina-image`?  Can something similar be done in react native you think?

Comment: @denistepp I haven't tried this library https://github.com/ladas-larry/react-native-responsive-image but you can see an approach with dimensions you can get scale and add your logic on which resource to use.